# Adding rows to MDL tables dynamically

Tags: javascript, material-design

I wish to add a new row to an MDL formatted table. But when I try to put the following class ... class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" ...

I get a few errors like:

> Refused to load the script 'https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

I have pasted relevant portions of the code below :

```
while(newlink!=null)
  {
    console.log(newlink);    
    var title = newlink.title;
    var url = newlink.url;
    if (title.length > 50)
      title = title.substr(0, 50) + "...";
    if (url.length > 50)
      url = url.substr(0, 50) + "...";
    var date = newlink.date;
    var time = newlink.time;
    var row = table.insertRow(i).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+i+"'><td id='title"+i+"'>"+title+"</td><td id='url"+i+"'>"+url+"</td><td id='date"+i+"'>"+date+"</td><td id='time"+i+"'>"+time+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+i+"' value='Edit' class='edit'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+i+"' value='Save' class='save' ></td></tr>";
```

I have included buttons to edit and save content at the end of each row.

Comment: Show your menifest.json

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to set `"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://code.getmdl.io; object-src 'self'",` in your manifest.json file  for references please have a look https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script